# Data-percent works only sometimes javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, github

(Sorry for bad english) Hi, I'm trying to make a JavaScript app which is basically a music player and I can't figure out why one thing is not working. There's a chart that displays the music percentage [(here's a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey93m.png) made with jQuery CDN and a [GitHub source](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart). The percentage resets at the beginning of the song (and this works) because of `songTime.dataset.percent = 0;`.
Then, there's the `songTime.dataset.percent = sliderPosition;` in a function that calculate at what point are you in the song

```
function chartUpdate() {
    let sliderPosition = 0;
    if (currentSong.duration != NaN) {
        sliderPosition = Math.round(currentSong.currentTime * (100 / currentSong.duration));
        songTime.dataset.percent = sliderPosition;
    }}
```

It is in an `if statement` which is in a function, but this doesn't work (it's not because of the variable, I've checked it).
I've tested it several times, and the only difference between the two lines is that the one that doesn't work is in an `if statement` (as I already said, which is in a function).
I know it can be difficult to understand me because there isn't any code (I tried to add it, but in stackoverflow it doesn't work, I don't know why), but if you need (I don't know if it can be helpful) I hosted the non-working website [here](https://alpacabaret-test.netlify.app/). Summing up, my problem is that the data-percent works only sometimes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will be more likely to get a proper answer if you format the question a little more cleanly. For example, moving the code that falls outside of the code formatting block into the block and breaking the non-code text into multiple paragraphs will make the post easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement contains invalid syntax. Replace

```
if (currentSong.duration != NaN)
```

with

```
if ( ! isNaN(currentSong.duration) )
```

Comment: The syntax is fine, the logic isn't, since NaN doesn't equal itself!

Comment: I've updated it and it still doesn't work, (https://alpacabaret-test2.netlify.app/). Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: I took a look at it. Slider position is updated correctly and songTime.dataset.percent as well. Looks like songTime.dataset.percent isn't the right parameter to update ... Can't help you with that unfortunately.